# Search for a word then copy the cell next to it into another Excel workbook with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I'm currently trying to search for "Quote ID:" in column A of workbook1, then copy the cell that is next to it in column B, and then paste that cell into cell B67 in workbook2.

Any ideas? I found some coding that is similar to what I need, but they were all more complex than I need it to be, and they were copying the entire row rather than the adjacent cell.

Comment: `copying the entire row rather than the adjacent cell` so you can't modify it to just one cell??

Answer (score 1):

Begin here:

```
Sub SingleCell()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range

    Set r1 = Workbooks("Book1").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Find(What:="Quote ID:").Offset(0, 1)
    Set r2 = Workbooks("Book2").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B67")
    r1.Copy r2
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

That shouldn't be too hard. But you'll have to fill in the workbook and worksheet names for it to work properly.

```
Sub searchMacro()

Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim srch As String
Dim col As Range, pstCell As Range, sRng As Range

'Identify workbooks
Set wb1 = Workbooks("workbook to search IDs Name")
Set wb2 = Workbooks("workbook to paste cell name")

'Identify worksheets
Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Sheet to search IDs Name")
Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("Sheet to paste cell name")

'Input which Quote to search for. This is a pop-up windows for the user to input the value into
srch = InputBox("Input Quote ID:", "Search ID")

'Search Column
Set col = ws1.Columns("A")

'Paste Cell
Set pstCell = ws2.Range("B67")

'Search the column for the ID
Set sRng = col.Find(srch)

If Not sRng Is Nothing Then
    'Quote ID was found
    sRng.Offset(0, 1).Copy pstCell
Else
    'Quote ID was not found
    MsgBox "Quote ID " & srch & " was not found", vbCritical, "Not found"
End If

End Sub
```

I hope that works for you